# Selenium Chrome profile managing driver_options.add_argument('--user_data_dir=<>) isn't working

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to us selenium to open a new session with defined profile (the purpose is to use the password autofill skills of chrome).

I used the add_argument option to manage selenium use the default dir of chrome. But when i running the code it keeps open the session with a guest window profile.

The relevant code is (Python 3.11):

```
driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Users/< my user >/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
options=driver_options)
```

And the session window it opens (without the profile settings):

[session pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKHW1.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using under_scores in your argument, but that should be this:

```
--user-data-dir=
```

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake typing it wrong in the first place. --user-data-dir= typed currectly and the problem exist (fixed it on the question body).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that profile directory should be defiend seperatly:

```
driver_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Users/< my user >/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data')
driver_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
```